# Invisible image in storyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, storyboard, assets

I have a quite simple `LaunchImage.storyboard`.

It contains one `UIViewController` (initial). I've added one `UIImageView` and set up the constraints.

Now, when I use image `Y` everything works fine - I can see the image both on the storyboard and on phone. However when I use image `X` I can see the image on the storyboard but on the phone it isn't visible (I can see only red background). The content mode of the imageView is `Aspect Fit`. Also, image `Y` is 30x30px, image `X` 400x400px.

Does anybody have an idea why the image is not visible on the phone?
I've tried deleting derived data, resetting Xcode, removing the app from the phone - still, the image is not visible.

Here are some of the images which present the situation:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

In the xcode:

[image]

On the phone (real screenshot of splash, just scaled it down):

[image]

Comment: show the screenshot of launchscreen and image here. . it will help

Comment: @baydi Here you are. A screenshot of xcode config and of the simulator.

Comment: try by giving the image in 2x section instead of 1x if you are giving the images in .assets folder

Comment: It is better to add three files one for each scale (@1x, @2x, @3x). If you would like to provide one file, check [this article](http://krakendev.io/blog/4-xcode-asset-catalog-secrets-you-need-to-know).

Also, in the attribute inspector for the image from the xcassets file, look for drop down menu "Render as"  and select "Original image".

Comment: @MuhammadArafat It has 3 sizes for each scale. Usually I prefer .pdfs instead of .pngs, but here it has to be .png. Anyway, it has 3 images inside the asset folder. Changing to the original image doesn't resolve the issue.

Comment: Hmm, try to remove the height and width constraints. Just keep the center horizontally and vertically, and may be add 400 height and width constraint.

Comment: @MuhammadArafat It seems to be a bug in the xcode. Check out my answer for details if you're interested in the topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a bug in Xcode 7:

My steps:

1. Had a project without the image.
2. Launched the app on iPhone 5 (ok)
3. Added `image A` and added it to the `launchscreen.storyboard`.
4. Launched on iPhone 5 - no image visible (bug)
5. Launched on iPhone 4s - saw `image A` (ok)
6. Changed image in assets from `image A` to `image B`
7. Launched on iPhone 4s - saw `image A` (bug)
8. Launched on iPhone 5 - no image visible (bug)
9. Launched on iPad mini - saw `image B`

Btw: I deleted the app between launches on the same device and deleted derived data on the Xcode.

Comment: I doubt it is a bug, but it sure is an annoying little problem. Gook luck figuring it out.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem today.

Try recreating your launch screen as a new storyboard file using the "LaunchScreen" template (instead of a generic storyboard). Make sure to name the file differently ("LaunchImage2" or something).

Don't know if that will solve your issue, but it worked for me.

Comment: I did it as Launchscreen :) However thanks for the info, if the issue persists I will try your solution. Xcode 7.1 GM is available in the appstore, maybe it'll solve the issue.